# Multithread control on application web

Tags: java, multithreading, web-applications, threadpool

I have a application that do some process on my server and after that deliver to the client.

```
http://application:8080/app/videos/download/{id}
```

where the "id" is the reference of a item for process.

If the user do the request again 10 times with different items, he will create 10 threads simultaneously, but i would like to create only three threads simultaneously per each user, and when this 3 over start the next three in a row. To not overflow the server.

I'm not succeeding implementing with threadpoolexecutor on web server, always when i make a new request he instantiate a new class again. i was thinking in a singleton pattern, but i would to create the threads per user, or different IP.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Some type of semaphore?

Comment: You are probably looking to use a [ContextListener](http://mrbool.com/using-servletcontextlistener-in-java/29326). It allows you to detect when a new session is created and destroyed.

Comment: Each user will have one session (per browser).  Put an "open requests" counter in each session.  when the counter is 3, fail the request.